# Starting a docker container with a bash script with parameters (container exited with code 0)

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I realize similar questions have been answered but nothing has worked for me so far.

I use docker and docker-compose on Windows.
I'm trying start a Bash script with parameters.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
&& apt-get -y install sudo \
&& echo "Set disable_coredump false" >> /etc/sudo.conf \
&& sudo apt-get install -y -q \
&& apt-get -y install python3.8 \
&& apt-get -y install python3.8-dev \
&& apt-get -y install python3-pip \
&& apt-get -y install git \
&& apt-get -y install curl \
&& mkdir prysm && cd prysm \
&& curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/master/prysm.sh --output prysm.sh && chmod +x prysm.sh 


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/prysm/prysm.sh", "beacon-chain", "--config-file=/beacon-config/config.yaml"]
```

The script prysm.sh starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

...and ends with:

```
 exec -a "$0" "${process}" "${@:2}"
```

The whole script can be seen here:
https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/blob/db9e02d7d10ac883df371cbb797ba8d03e88619c/prysm.sh

My docker-compose.yaml file is in the same folder as the dockerfile. Here is its content:

```
version: "3"
services:
    beacon-node:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3500:3500"
            - "4000:4000"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
         - ./data:/beacon-node-data
         - ./keys:/beacon-keys
         - ./config:/beacon-config
```

The command *docker-compose up* gives me the following result:

```
Starting ethereum2beaconnode_beacon-node_1 ... done
Attaching to ethereum2beaconnode_beacon-node_1
ethereum2beaconnode_beacon-node_1 exited with code 0
```

I have tried checking the logs of the container with this command:

```
docker logs ethereum2beaconnode_beacon-node_1
```

But it returns an empty line.

I have tried many thing but nothing worked so far. I am at loss.

Comment: Additionally tot he selected answer, I was missing a step: building with docker-compose. I was on only building with docker. As a consequence docker-compose didn't have the latest image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENTRYPOINT is not correct, replace it with :

```
CMD ["/prysm/prysm.sh", "beacon-chain", "--config-file=/beacon-config/config.yaml"]
```

When I ran `docker-compose up`, I got

```
Creating docker_beacon-node_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_beacon-node_1
beacon-node_1  | Latest Prysm version is v1.0.0-alpha.17.
beacon-node_1  | Downloading beacon chain@v1.0.0-alpha.17 to /prysm/dist/beacon-chain-v1.0.0-alpha.17-linux-amd64 (automatically selected latest available version)
beacon-node_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
beacon-node_1  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 42.5M  100 42.5M    0     0  3272k      0  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:-- 3316k
beacon-node_1  | Verifying binary integrity.
beacon-node_1  | gpg: key 72E33E4DF1A5036E: public key "Preston Van Loon <preston@prysmaticlabs.com>" imported
beacon-node_1  | gpg: Total number processed: 1
beacon-node_1  | gpg:               imported: 1
beacon-node_1  | beacon-chain-v1.0.0-alpha.17-linux-amd64: OK
beacon-node_1  | gpg: Signature made Fri Jul 31 03:31:33 2020 UTC
beacon-node_1  | gpg:                using RSA key 0AE0051D647BA3C1A917AF4072E33E4DF1A5036E
beacon-node_1  | gpg: Good signature from "Preston Van Loon <preston@prysmaticlabs.com>" [unknown]
beacon-node_1  | gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
beacon-node_1  | gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
beacon-node_1  | Primary key fingerprint: 0AE0 051D 647B A3C1 A917  AF40 72E3 3E4D F1A5 036E
beacon-node_1  | Verified /prysm/dist/beacon-chain-v1.0.0-alpha.17-linux-amd64 has been signed by Prysmatic Labs.
beacon-node_1  | Starting Prysm beacon-chain --config-file=/beacon-config/config.yaml
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping docker_beacon-node_1 ... done
```

with ENTRYPOINT, I got :

```
Recreating docker_beacon-node_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_beacon-node_1
beacon-node_1  | Usage: ./prysm.sh PROCESS FLAGS.
beacon-node_1  |        ./prysm.sh PROCESS --download-only.
beacon-node_1  | PROCESS can be beacon-chain, validator, or slasher.
docker_beacon-node_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: You are right. Your answer works. 
It started working when I built using: docker-compose build  
Before that, I would just do: docker build . and then docker-compose up